# Can I reduce code in repeat declarations?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to reduce code for repeat declarations in Obj-C?

E.g.:

I have

```
    localNotification.fireDate = self.dueDate;
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.alertBody = self.text;
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
```

Can it be simplified to something like this?

```
 localNotification
    .fireDate = self.dueDate;
    .timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    .alertBody = self.text;
    .soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Autocomplete is your friend!

Comment: Change the name of the variable from `localNotification` to `l`. Less typing but also less readable.

Comment: @rmaddy interesting idea but is `l` really explanatory as to what its doing.. better to use `localNotification`.

Comment: @logixologist That's why I said it would be less readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use Key-Value-Coding. First pack the values into a dictionary with the property names as keys

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"fireDate": self.dueDate,
                                 @"timeZone":[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone],
                                 @"alertBody":self.text,
                                 @"soundName": UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName }
```

<strike>, than you can easily enumerate the keys and objects with a block.</strike>

```
[parameters enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^(id key, 
                                                 id object, 
                                                 BOOL *stop) 
{
    [localNotification setValue:object forKey:key];
}];
```

If you would use this code over and over again, I'd create a category on NSNotification wth an method that takes the dictionary and dies the enumeration.

Than you can simply use

```
[localNotification setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:parameters];
```

[docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/setValuesForKeysWithDictionary%3a)

---

Of course you can write it even shorter:

```
[localNotification setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:@{@"fireDate": self.dueDate,
                                                    @"timeZone":[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone],
                                                    @"alertBody":self.text,
                                                    @"soundName": UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName }];
```

Now it is nearly as compact as the proposed syntax.

Comment: Or `-setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:`... ;)

Comment: damn — I hate reinventing the wheel…

Comment: interesting, though then you can't use autocomplete for fireDate, timeZone, etc.

autocompleting 'localNotification' seems to be the easiest way.

Answer (score 2):

The only way would be to declare a method that takes the parameters you are wanting to set.

```
-(void)notification:(UILocalNotification *)notification setFireDate:(NSDate *)date
   setAlertBody:(NSString *)alertBody {

   notification.fireDate = date;
   notification.alertBody = alertBody;
   notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
   notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName; 
}
```

The second two lines could be considered setting up a "default". Change those lines to whatever a default value you'd want.  Then...

```
UILocalNotification *myNotification = ...
NSDate *tenMinutesAway = [NSDate ... 
[self notification:myNotification setFireDate:tenMinutesAway setAlertBody:@"Hello world!"];
```

You could also look at subclassing `UILocalNotification` and in the `-init` method set up a bunch of default behavior there, which would save you ever having to type `.soundName` and `.timeZone` again

Comment: You could also do this with a category, and a method that takes an NSDictionary as a parameter, keyed however you want. Maybe a little overkill.

Comment: How does this achieve the goal in the question? The question isn't about making it easier to set the same group of properties for multiple objects. The question is if there is a shortcut to the property syntax to avoid specifying the same object over and over.